# Return Value of MinGW gcc

Tags: batch-file, mingw

I have set my path with the portion ";C:\MinGW\bin;"

And my different C Sources in different carpets to compile one basic I found in the very good C Windows Tutorial in http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html absolutly basic, as recomended there this means without a make file as I use todo.

But it's boring to change the directory into the carpet where the source is I want compile, so I wrote a batch file old style:
echo File:        MinimalWnd.bat
echo Project:     MinimalWnd                                                                                            *
echo Started:     15.01.2022
echo Last Edited: 15.01.2022                                                                                       *                                                                *                                                                                           *
echo Autor: Wolfgang Jakobi, 14199 Berlin

```
cd C:\Users\Wolfg\documents\Programmierung\MinGW\MinGW_Projekt\GetLanguageRegistry
echo echo %path%
echo compile MiniMalWnd.c with gcc
gcc MiniMalWnd.c -o MiniMalWnd
```

I want to add

```
if (r = result of gcc) > 0 
  echo successfully
else
  echo failed
```

But returns gcc a value?

Comment: Either add `&& (echo successfully) || echo failed` to your last line, or add a new line underneath your last one, `if errorlevel 1 (echo failed) else echo successfully`.

Comment: I become aware that I wrote my last bach file in the 1970ies too long ago I forgot mean while the essencials